# Do unique constraints get checked one by one?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a simple `users` table

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (id uuid, name varchar)
```

users can propose each other, so we have another table called `proposals`

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_proposals (id uuid, user_id uuid, proposed_user_id uuid)
```

We want to define a unique constraints so a user can't propose another specific user twice.

Does defining unique constraints with columns of (user_id, proposed_user_id) also prevents `proposed_user_id` from proposing `user_id` ? in other words, does postgres check unique constraint in reverse as well? (proposed_user_id, user_id)

Comment: `UNIQUE` check is performed on the tuple. `(A, B) != (B, A)` if `A != B`. So unique constraint will not prevent insertion of any permutations of tuple's elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to assert that no user pairing exists in either direction, you would have to use an insert trigger.  A constraint can only assert something on the values being inserted in that record, not against the entire table.

One suggestion here might be to create a unique constraint on (`user_id`, `proposed_user_id`), and also add a constraint asserting that `user_id` is always less than `proposed_user_id`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_proposals (
    id uuid,
    user_id uuid,
    proposed_user_id uuid,
    UNIQUE(user_id, proposed_user_id),
    CHECK (user_id < proposed_user_id)
)
```

With this definition in place, you only would need to ensure that you insert the smaller `id` value for `user_id`, and the larger for `proposed_user_id`.  The constraints would handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is actually the first time I have seen UUIDs being compared for their values, would you mind explaining how that works further?

Comment: @typicallearner UUIDs can be compared using inequalities, you may try it yourself to see.  BTW...the answer by Laurenz is probably closer to what you actually want here.  But my answer can work too, if you can enforce that you always will insert the earlier UUID before the later one.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "earlier" UUID? do UUIDs that are generated in the past always smaller than UUIDs generated in the future?

Comment: @typicallearner ... they are compared numerically.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON users (
   least(user_id, proposed_user_id),
   greatest(user_id, proposed_user_id),
);
```